# openssl s_client not offering the specified protocol version in handshake

Tags: ssl, openssl

Several of my machines are having trouble connecting to certain HTTPS servers on the internet.   To debug this I've begun to learn `openssl s_client` and the TLS 1.2 protocol and now am perplexed by something as I debug:

On some of my machines, if I invoke

```
openssl s_client -debug  -tls1_2 -connect admin.fedorahosted.org:443
```

the client starts the handshake with hex bytes

```
16 03 03 ...
```

but on most machines it begins with

```
16 03 01 ...
```

The former indicates that the protocol will be TLS 1.2 and the later indicates that it will be TLS 1.0.   The former sounds reasonable because I specified that right on the command line, but it seems odd to me that the second one would occur given that I've explicitly requested TLS 1.2.

I've done `yum update` on all the CentOS machines tested so they are all nominally at the same level of openssl.

What might be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL/TLS is a ''record based'' protocol, each record has a version field in the 5 byte header, that's what you are seeing in the (unencrypted) handshake records that are used to setup the cipher and protocol version.

Within the handshake exchange, the protocol version and the cipher are negotiated in the "hello" records. The [client hello](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2) contains a field with the highest version the client supports, and the [server hello](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.3) (in reply) contains the lowest shared version. There's an assumption that the client and server support a contiguous range of versions, if they do not overlap a protocol version alert is sent (at which point a client may retry with a different version).

[RFC 5246 Appendix E](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-E) details the expected logic for attempting a connection and determining a protocol. It also contains a note on the problem you may be observing:

> Note: some server implementations are known to implement version
> negotiation incorrectly.  For example, there are buggy TLS 1.0
> servers that simply close the connection when the client offers a
> version newer than TLS 1.0.  Also, it is known that some servers will
> refuse the connection if any TLS extensions are included in
> ClientHello.  Interoperability with such buggy servers is a complex
> topic beyond the scope of this document, and may require multiple
> connection attempts by the client.

For a long time it was not uncommon to see SSLv2.0 on the first packet ("client hello") to maximise interoperability, but you should only see that on very old software nowadays (especially since there's no support for [SNI and various other extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3546), which require at least TLSv1.0). There's a little more background in this Security.SE question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34827/why-clients-offer-handshaking-with-ssl-2-0-protocol

Now, as to *why* you are seeing different behaviour across your systems, I cannot tell without the CentOS and package versions. You may double check your OpenSSL version with `openssl version -a` to see if there are patch level differences. Red Hat (and hence CentOS) include substantial patches to OpenSSL (in addition to removing various patented algorithms, there are about 65 patches to alter behaviour or back-port patches and features).  The [CHANGES](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable/CHANGES) for (official) 1.0.1a describes what you are seeing, though I'm guessing here:

> ```
> *) Workarounds for some broken servers that "hang" if a client hello
> ```

```
   record length exceeds 255 bytes.
```

> 

```
   1. Do not use record version number > TLS 1.0 in initial client
      hello: some (but not all) hanging servers will now work.
   2. [...]
```

Comment: What a thorough answer.   Now all the machines are behaving the same way so I can not dig any further at my end.  If I encounter this again though, I'll have this post to guide me.  Thanks !